# Pipenv fails locking when installing TensorFlow 2.4.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, pipenv

2021-02-06: I ended up with installing TensorFlow using `pip`.

The original question is shown below.

As I mentioned in the title, pipenv fails to lock when installing TensorFlow (ver. 2.4.1).
I would like to know the solution for this problem.

The current environment is:
macOS Big Sur 11.1
python 3.8.7 (pyenv-installed)
pyenv 1.2.22 (homebrew-installed)
pipenv 2020.11.15 (homebrew-installed)
pip 21.0

What I did and responses are:

1. `mkdir ~/tf && cd ~/tf`
2. `pyenv local 3.8.7` -> changes to python 3.8.7
3. `pipenv --python 3.8.7` -> creates the virtual environment and Pipfile
4. `pipenv shell`
5. `pip install --upgrade pip` -> upgrades pip from 20.2.4 to 21.0
6. `pipenv install tensorflow` ->

```
Installing tensorflow...
Adding tensorflow to Pipfile's [packages]...
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed! 
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 741, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(pre, clear, verbose, system, write, requirements_dir, packages, dev)
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 702, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, resolver = resolve(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 684, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       return resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1395, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, hashes, markers_lookup, resolver, skipped = actually_resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1108, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 833, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: Could not find a version that matches tensorflow (from -r /var/folders/66/qc27xk113h97ysq8g96dq6lw0000gn/T/pipenvi9b634u2requirements/pipenv-rgesnhxh-constraints.txt (line 2))
No versions found
Was https://pypi.org/simple reachable?
```

I tried `pipenv lock --clear`, but it did not work and returned the same error message above.

It seems that TensorFlow is successfully installed since `python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'` returns `2.4.1`, and its version supports Python 3.8.7.
I also tried installing TensorFlow using `pip` outside the virtual environment, and it successfully installed TensorFlow 2.4.1.

Here is the result of `pipenv graph` and it seems there is no dependency conflict (there might be conflicts that I do not notice).

```
tensorflow==2.4.1
  - absl-py [required: ~=0.10, installed: 0.11.0]
    - six [required: Any, installed: 1.15.0]
  - astunparse [required: ~=1.6.3, installed: 1.6.3]
    - six [required: >=1.6.1,<2.0, installed: 1.15.0]
    - wheel [required: >=0.23.0,<1.0, installed: 0.36.2]
  - flatbuffers [required: ~=1.12.0, installed: 1.12]
  - gast [required: ==0.3.3, installed: 0.3.3]
  - google-pasta [required: ~=0.2, installed: 0.2.0]
    - six [required: Any, installed: 1.15.0]
  - grpcio [required: ~=1.32.0, installed: 1.32.0]
    - six [required: >=1.5.2, installed: 1.15.0]
  - h5py [required: ~=2.10.0, installed: 2.10.0]
    - numpy [required: >=1.7, installed: 1.19.5]
    - six [required: Any, installed: 1.15.0]
  - keras-preprocessing [required: ~=1.1.2, installed: 1.1.2]
    - numpy [required: >=1.9.1, installed: 1.19.5]
    - six [required: >=1.9.0, installed: 1.15.0]
  - numpy [required: ~=1.19.2, installed: 1.19.5]
  - opt-einsum [required: ~=3.3.0, installed: 3.3.0]
    - numpy [required: >=1.7, installed: 1.19.5]
  - protobuf [required: >=3.9.2, installed: 3.14.0]
    - six [required: >=1.9, installed: 1.15.0]
  - six [required: ~=1.15.0, installed: 1.15.0]
  - tensorboard [required: ~=2.4, installed: 2.4.1]
    - absl-py [required: >=0.4, installed: 0.11.0]
      - six [required: Any, installed: 1.15.0]
    - google-auth [required: >=1.6.3,<2, installed: 1.24.0]
      - cachetools [required: >=2.0.0,<5.0, installed: 4.2.1]
      - pyasn1-modules [required: >=0.2.1, installed: 0.2.8]
        - pyasn1 [required: >=0.4.6,<0.5.0, installed: 0.4.8]
      - rsa [required: >=3.1.4,<5, installed: 4.7]
        - pyasn1 [required: >=0.1.3, installed: 0.4.8]
      - setuptools [required: >=40.3.0, installed: 50.3.2]
      - six [required: >=1.9.0, installed: 1.15.0]
    - google-auth-oauthlib [required: >=0.4.1,<0.5, installed: 0.4.2]
      - google-auth [required: Any, installed: 1.24.0]
        - cachetools [required: >=2.0.0,<5.0, installed: 4.2.1]
        - pyasn1-modules [required: >=0.2.1, installed: 0.2.8]
          - pyasn1 [required: >=0.4.6,<0.5.0, installed: 0.4.8]
        - rsa [required: >=3.1.4,<5, installed: 4.7]
          - pyasn1 [required: >=0.1.3, installed: 0.4.8]
        - setuptools [required: >=40.3.0, installed: 50.3.2]
        - six [required: >=1.9.0, installed: 1.15.0]
      - requests-oauthlib [required: >=0.7.0, installed: 1.3.0]
        - oauthlib [required: >=3.0.0, installed: 3.1.0]
        - requests [required: >=2.0.0, installed: 2.25.1]
          - certifi [required: >=2017.4.17, installed: 2020.12.5]
          - chardet [required: >=3.0.2,<5, installed: 4.0.0]
          - idna [required: >=2.5,<3, installed: 2.10]
          - urllib3 [required: >=1.21.1,<1.27, installed: 1.26.3]
    - grpcio [required: >=1.24.3, installed: 1.32.0]
      - six [required: >=1.5.2, installed: 1.15.0]
    - markdown [required: >=2.6.8, installed: 3.3.3]
    - numpy [required: >=1.12.0, installed: 1.19.5]
    - protobuf [required: >=3.6.0, installed: 3.14.0]
      - six [required: >=1.9, installed: 1.15.0]
    - requests [required: >=2.21.0,<3, installed: 2.25.1]
      - certifi [required: >=2017.4.17, installed: 2020.12.5]
      - chardet [required: >=3.0.2,<5, installed: 4.0.0]
      - idna [required: >=2.5,<3, installed: 2.10]
      - urllib3 [required: >=1.21.1,<1.27, installed: 1.26.3]
    - setuptools [required: >=41.0.0, installed: 50.3.2]
    - six [required: >=1.10.0, installed: 1.15.0]
    - tensorboard-plugin-wit [required: >=1.6.0, installed: 1.8.0]
    - werkzeug [required: >=0.11.15, installed: 1.0.1]
    - wheel [required: >=0.26, installed: 0.36.2]
  - tensorflow-estimator [required: >=2.4.0,<2.5.0, installed: 2.4.0]
  - termcolor [required: ~=1.1.0, installed: 1.1.0]
  - typing-extensions [required: ~=3.7.4, installed: 3.7.4.3]
  - wheel [required: ~=0.35, installed: 0.36.2]
  - wrapt [required: ~=1.12.1, installed: 1.12.1]
```

If you have experienced the same issue and solved it, please let me know how to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: If you're OK with workarounds: [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) has a different dependency resolution algorithm than pipenv and might just happen to work. In practice I also find that it's much faster and is easier to work with.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for your suggestion. I'll consider the use of poetry.

Comment: Follow the instructions mentioned in the [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#ubuntu-macos) site to Install Tensorflow on MacOS. Thanks!

Comment: @TFer Thank you for your comment. I ended up with installing Tensorflow using pip because I could not resolve the issue and the similar issue occurred when using poetry too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up installing TF with Pipenv, instead, I installed TF with pip.
As TF official website suggests, installing TF with pip might be the best solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you were able to resolve this. But I was stuck with the same issue.
A simple pipenv clear and then a pipenv sync (which reinstalls dependencies from the pipfile) help resolving the issue
Eventually pip lock was successfull

Comment: Thank you for your suggested solution.
But recently, I purchased m1 mac, and it turned out that Pyenv + Pipenv solution is not ideal for m1 macs.
So I no longer use Pipenv, and thus cannot check if your suggested solution works, but thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered numerous locking issues with pipenv on Big Sur. I've been able to consistently resolve them (including this TF installation issue) by running:

```
export SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=1
```

before doing anything with pipenv.

Essentially it makes your shell identify itself as Catalina to pipenv.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I mentioned in the past, I ended up with installing TF with pip, and it turned out that venv + pip works just fine for me. Well, thank you for your solution.